# Trying to run a java application from a shell script on Ubuntu 10.04

Tags: java, ubuntu-10.04

My java program was written on a windows machine and I am trying to get it installed and running on a Ubuntu 10.04 machine. I have created a .tar.gz file with myProgram.jar in it as well as 5 supporting library .jar files in a lib folder. Where do I put these files? Do I need to extract it on the Linux machine to a usr/bin folder? Does the shell script go inside the tar.gz? I have read that if you write the shell script on a windows machine you can have issues once you move it to the Linux machine, so I am writing the shell script on the Linux machine using gedit. I am just not sure what to do next.
So far in my script I have,

```
#!/bin/bash 
java -jar myProgram.jar
```

I am going to try and extract the tar.gz file to the usr/bin directory and see if it runs. 
Any suggestions or help would be greatly appreciated.
Thanks in advance,
Ray

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question is quite "broad" :). I hope you find the following useful.

Do not extract the files to /usr/bin. See e.g. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Filesystem_Hierarchy_Standard on where and where not to put files on a *nix system.

1. Extract the jar's to e.g. /opt/yourProgram/*.
2. The shell script should be inside there too. Make sure its *executable* (i.e chmod 755 script.sh)
3. In your shell script add `cd /opt/yourProgram` to have the proper working directory for your program before you invoke `java`.
4. If you want this program to be started easily by everyone create a *symbolic link* in `/usr/bin` or better in `/usr/local/bin` pointing to your script. Do this as last step after everything else is working.

In your shell script you'll have to add the other jars to the classpath e.g.

`java -cp lib/some.jar:lib/other.jar -jar myProgram.jar`

or

`java -cp lib/some.jar:lib/other.jar:myProgram.jar com.acme.ClassContainingMain`

Recommended practice: Add `set -e` at the very beginning of your script

As you already mentioned it's considered harmful to edit a shell script using a windows editor. The reason is that the windows editor will encode line-breaks (i.e. you hit the Return key) differently. This will make bash puke :)

Comment: Thanks Martin. This definitely got me headed in the right direction. I will create a new question if I get stuck again.

Answer (score 0):

Im not too clear of what you are looking for.

The script that you have written should work absolutely fine if you have placed your script and myprogram.jar at the same level.

And also im not sure how your myprogram.jar is referring the dependent libraries. So can't comment on them. Best bet will be to place your script and all jars together and try running the script.

Comment: I have saved my script as myProgram.sh on the desktop which is the same place I have myProgram.jar and a lib folder containing the other .jar files. When I try and run the .sh file by double clicking it opens it in gedit. If I try to run the .jar file from the terminal with "java -jar myProgram.jar" I get "unable to access jarfile myProgram.jar".

Comment: Is the *.sh file executable?.

Comment: check whether the .sh file has required permission to execute. then type ./myProgram.sh

Comment: Thanks for the help guys. I really appreciate it. I am still having trouble. I will post a new question once I figure out where I am stuck.